# Multiplication table in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I have this problem---

Write code that will print a multiplication table for 10 positive integers across the columns and 10 positive integers down the rows. Prompt the user for the starting values for both the columns and the rows.

My attempt after some explanation from another question, which doesn't print like Id expect it. Where do I call the print statements and what is wrong with the iterations

```
row = int(raw_input("Enter the first row number: "   ))
col = int(raw_input("Enter the frist column number: "))

lastRow = row + 10
lastCol = col + 10


while (row < lastRow):
    print "%4d" % (col * row) 
    while(col < lastCol):

       print "%4d" % (col * row),
       col += 1

    print "%4d" % (col * row) 
    row += 1
```

Here's a second go,  better but not what I thought get

```
     row = int(raw_input("Enter the first row number: "   ))
     col = int(raw_input("Enter the frist column number: "))

     lastRow = row + 10
     lastCol = col + 10

    x=row
    y=col

    while (x < lastRow):
        while(y < lastCol):
            y += 1
            print "%4d" % (y * x)
       x += 1
```

Sorry about the duplicate post, I didn't know that was bad etiquette

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python user input and multiplication table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990991/python-user-input-and-multiplication-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick edit that does the trick:

```
row = int(raw_input("Enter the first row number: "   ))
col = int(raw_input("Enter the frist column number: "))

lastRow = row + 5
firstCol = col
lastCol = col + 5

while (row < lastRow):
    while(col < lastCol):
        print "%4d" % (col * row),
        col += 1

    col = firstCol
    row += 1
    print
```

Problems in your code:

1. `col` kept at `lastCol` value in the end of first cycle iteration. It should be reset to starting point after each row
2. Too many unnecessary `print`'s
3. `row` increment should be done inside of first `while`

And a tip: if you get stuck with problems like this, get a piece of paper, put down simple and small starting values: row = 1, col = 1, up to 3's instead of 10's. And reproduce your algorithm by hand, step by step.

Comment: Thank you I didn't understand that the row increment was to be in the first while and, I just forgot that I would have to save the intital value, coding is still alien to me,

Answer (score 3):

(1) Your `col` variable is not getting reset for each new row.
It is just always incrementing.

Maybe use another pair of variables, like `r` and `c` for the iteration itself.

Or store the original row and col in differently-named variables.

(2) Your indentation of the last two lines seems wrong - shouldn't it be inside the first `while` loop?

(3) You do not need so many print statements.
You should only need one print statement in the inner loop, and another (empty one) to end each line.

**Update**: Please don't post duplicate questions

Comment: fixed the indents typo here, so I need to store the original row and  col  outside the loop?

Comment: @user1020349: Yes. See Stanislav's answer.

Comment: Sorry about the duplicate post, I didn't know that was bad etiquette